# Monitor executed SQL statements from external application

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-express

I have an external application connecting to a SQL Server 2008 Express database.

Is it possible to monitor (view) the SQL statements that are generated by the external application at all? I am trying to work out the tables (and the relevant joins) used in the queries.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The best i can think of will be to use [SP_whoisactive](http://whoisactive.com) from Adam Machanic which is very quick to generate a table to collect the data you need, then run the procedure in a loop with a wait statement to regularly collect the data you want over an interval.

You can gather the data as explained [here](http://www.brentozar.com/responder/log-sp_whoisactive-to-a-table/) to log the activities on the system with help of SP_whoisactive.

However , you may always go with live monitoring using [SQL profiler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190378.aspx) and gather the required data accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can start up SQL Profiler and run a trace to see exactly what statements are being run.

Make sure to tick "Show all columns". Then go into "Column Filters" and add the Host Name you want to monitor into the HostName filter - this will then only show you queries coming from this host. If you do happen to have other apps on the same host you can also limit the trace by other filters "e.g. LoginName" until you are tracing only the relevant information.

Run the trace.

Comment: Is this available under Express edition?  I cannot find it or work out how to get it installed.